# I'm currently writing Xpredict function which is a wrapper for keras.predict function() for all the keras model in general

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to know how do I find the corresponding class name of the predictions?

Generator.class_indices works for few of the models where the data is coming from generator. However, for few models where the data is not coming from generator it throws an error saying

AttributeError: 'NumpyArrayIterator' object has no attribute 'class_indices'

```
def xpredict(self, img_path, batch_size = None, verbose = 0, steps = None):
        x = image.load_img(img_path, target_size = Sequential.input_shape)
        x = image.img_to_array(x)
        x = np.expand_dims(x, axis = 0)
        result = self.predict(x, batch_size = batch_size, verbose = verbose, steps = None)
        for key, value in Sequential.generator.class_indices.items():
            if value == result:
                return key
```

Expected:

I want to know how to write a general function to predict the class_name from any keras general model.

Actual:

only works for training_data coming from generator using generator.class_indices.

Comment: What do you mean by image name/id? The class name is not generally part of the model, that is external to keras.

Comment: True. It's not part of keras. Is there a way that I can get it from source code. There are times that developer defines them in their python file or sometimes the developer use the folder-names as class names. I want to know is it possible to write a generic function that returns the class name to my xpredict function other than restricting the developer to give us the class names

Comment: No, probably not, you can signal the developers about the class names, its something they have to provide.

Comment: Okay, Thanks MatiasValdenegro

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this in general, the class names is something the developer has to provide, Keras does not know about this and it is not stored anywhere.